# Jasper on a jsf app in heroku

Tags: jsf, heroku, jasper-reports, jetty

I am working in an application that uses jasperreports. It uses Primefaces with Mojarra, and is deployed in Jetty. When I deploy the app locally, it does work ok. But when I deploy in heroku it is not working.

When I deploy it to heroku I obtain:

> HTTP ERROR 500

```
 Problem accessing /pages/client.jsf. Reason:
```

> ```
>   STREAM Caused by:
> ```

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAM    at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.getWriter(Response.java:683)     at
     com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:723)
        at
     com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:930)
        at
     com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:376)
        at
     com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at
     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
     org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1367)
        at
     org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1338)
        at
     org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
        at
     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1338)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:484)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)  at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:900)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:954)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:851)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:620)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
        at
     org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

As you can see it is deployed using Jetty.

The code that sends the pdf report is this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="reportGeneratorMB")
@RequestScoped
public class ReportGeneratorMB {
    public void generateReport(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException, IOException, JRException {
        Connection connection;
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext()
                .getResponse();
        InputStream reportStream = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(
                "/resources/reports/index.jasper");
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sid", "sid", 
                "sid");
        facesContext.getExternalContext().setResponseContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, new HashMap(),
                connection);
        connection.close();
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    }
}
```

And in the c.xhtml:

```
...
<h:form id="reportForm">
    <p:commandButton value="Generate Report" id="generate_report"
            actionListener="#{reportGeneratorMB.generateReport} ajax="false"/>
</form>
...
```

I've searched by I still haven't found a thing that can help me, and since it is working locally I do not know what can I do. I am not sure if this data is enough, but if it isn't I'll be grateful if you tell me what information I need to provide to get some help.

Thanks in advance,

Juan G

Comment: The pasted stacktrace has no mention of `generateReport()` in it.

Answer (score 0):

The error ...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAM at
   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.getWriter(Response.java:683) at
```

... means that your access to [`ServletResponse.getWriter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) failed because something else in your application has previously accessed [`ServletResponse.getOutputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29).  That is not allowed per the servlet spec.  You can either use a Writer or an OutputStream for your response, but not both.  See javadoc on both of those methods for `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Joakim, but how does it make sense that it is working locally?

Comment: without details on how every request is processed and routed through your container + jfaces + heroku + spring + primeface noone can answer that followup question.  Your chosen technologies are sane, but your question contains none of the detail required to answer that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Joakim. I have just edited the question adding some more info. However I'm still not sure if what I added is enough.

Comment: It seems that the information I added was not enough, so I am trying to change the approach (I was using a ManagedBean, and now I am using a Servlet). I am having different problems, so I am starting a new question for the new approach. Thanks @Joakim I am pretty sure that your answer is OK, and that is the reason why I am trying the new approach (I believe it can be something related to managedbeans and jsf). I still do not know why it was working locally and only failed when deployed to heroku and that's why I am not marking (yet) your answer as correct.

Comment: Hi I am having the same issue, have you found the cause and the solution ? thanks