# Jasper report on heroku in a jsf app

Tags: java, servlets, heroku, jasper-reports

I am working in an application that uses jasperreports. It uses Primefaces with Mojarra, and is deployed in Jetty. When I deploy the app locally, it does work ok. But when I deploy in heroku it is not working.

When I deploy it to heroku I obtain:

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /clients.pdf. Reason:
>
> ```
> Server Error Caused by:
> ```
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2310)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2323)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:58)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:244)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:229)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:405)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:201)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:720)
>     at
>   co.qcsc.spatha.web.servlet.ReportServlet.generateReport(ReportServlet.java:62)
>     at
>   co.qcsc.spatha.web.servlet.ReportServlet.processRequest(ReportServlet.java:37)
>     at
>   co.qcsc.spatha.web.servlet.ReportServlet.doGet(ReportServlet.java:25)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1367)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:484)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

The code that sends the pdf report is this:

```
public class ReportServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        generateReport(request, response);
    }

    public void generateReport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection connection;
        InputStream reportStream =getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(
                "/resources/reports/index.jasper");
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sid", "sid",
                    "sid");
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, new HashMap(),
                    connection);
            connection.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
    }
```

And in the c.xhtml:

```
...
    <h:form id="reportForm">
        <p:commandButton value="Generate Report" id="generate_report"
                oncomplete="reportDialogWidget.show()"/>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog id="reportDialog" modal="true" widgetVar="reportDialogWidget" dynamic="true" resizable="true" maximizable="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
        <iframe src="/clients.pdf" width="800" height="600"></iframe>
    </p:dialog>
...
```

The section related to this servlet in web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ReportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jg.servlet.ReportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ReportServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/clients.pdf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I've been searching, but I have not found anything that helps me. I think this is information  is enough to get some help, but if I am missing something please let me know, I will add anything needed.

Thanks in advance for reading my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jasper on a jsf app in heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706638/jasper-on-a-jsf-app-in-heroku)

Comment: @AlexK This is not a duplicate. If you read it, it's me asking for two different errors with two different approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something with this line:

```
InputStream reportStream =getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(
            "/resources/reports/index.jasper");
```

When you get resource as stream, you have to make sure the resource exist. Heroku might not be finding it. Check that it was committed too or better still check for null pointer exception on reportStream before using it.

Comment: Thank you @unekwu I've checked it. The resource have been committed. And yes, I can check for NullPointerException... but I still can not show the pdf with the data I need. Any other idea?

Comment: I'm so amazingly stupid! Thank you @unekwu, I was checking for index.jrxml... not index.jasper

Comment: Well, we have all made similar mistakes